# SP2013 SPD workflow - Is Trigerring but not getting executed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-server

I have a SP2013 on-prem farm with many site collections.

SPD workflows are getting triggered but not getting executed.

Both existing and new workflows are getting Triggered but not getting executed.

[image]

Comment: Are these 2013 Workflows?  Do 2010 Workflows work as expected?  If so i'd start by checking out your 2013 WFM farm / server and verifying that the WFM client is installed on the SP servers.

Comment: @JoshMcClanahan Yes, Workflows created as SP2010 workflow type are working fine.